# writing custom cast in typescript

Tags: typescript

In C# we can implement customized type casting through `implicit` or `explicit` operator overloading. For example:

```
public class A {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public static implicit operator A(B b) {
        A a = new A();
        a.Name = b.PhoneNumber;
        return a;
    }
}
```

This allows use to cast `B` to `A` like `B b = new B(); A a = b;`

Is there any way to do this in typescript so that the given following types:

```
class A {
    name?: string | null | undefined;
}
class B {
    phoneNumber?: string | null | undefined;
}
```

`B` can be cast to `A` the following way:

```
const b: B = { phoneNumber: "1234" }
const a: A = (A)b
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't really have any kind of operator overloading. The closest thing in terms of ease of use would probably be a static method on `A` accepting values of type `B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In C# we can implement customized type casting through implicit or explicit operator overloading

There is no operator overloading in TypeScript

## Why?

Because there is no operator overloading in JavaScript. TypeScript doesn't like to add runtime features that are not supported by JavaScript.

## Alternative

Create a static method in class A

```
class A {
    name?: string | null | undefined;
    static fromB(value: B): A {
      // ... TODO
    }
}
class B {
    phoneNumber?: string | null | undefined;
}

const b: B = { phoneNumber: "1234" }
const a: A = A.fromB(b)
```

PS: I prefer that static function over operator overloading even if it was supported by JavaScript